# Using TextKit with storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, autolayout, textkit

I have a `UITextView` in a storyboard with a `UINavigationController`, which looks like this:

[image]

It has an autolayout constraint at the top to prevent the uppermost text from being hidden beneath the navigation bar and a constraint to the left, right and bottom.

I need to make use of a custom `NSTextStorage` subclass, which I understand requires me to instantiate the `UITextView` manually and insert it into the view. My question is, how do I mimic these constraints with code?

Here is the code I've written to initialize the UITextView:

```
_textStorage = [[MyCustomTextStorage alloc] initWithString:@"some string"];

_layoutManager = [NSLayoutManager new];
[_textStorage addLayoutManager: _layoutManager];

_textContainer = [NSTextContainer new];
[_layoutManager addTextContainer: _textContainer];

_textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds textContainer:_textContainer];

[self.view addSubview:_textView];
```

As an aside, I could get around this if there were a way to use a custom `UITextStorage` subclass with a `UITextView` in a storyboard, am I mistaken in thinking this is impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question, the solution here was to subclass UITextView, implement my custom behaviour in the subclass and then set the UITextView in the storyboard to use the subclass. This lets me maintain the initial set of constraints from the storyboard.

Comment: Unrelated to your specific question but you could pin the text view to all edges of the superview and have the view controller automatically adjust the insets so your text flows behind the navigation bar